# IsFinite() equivalent

Tags: c#, c++

What is the C# replacement for the following define?

```
#define IS_FINITE(x) (0x7FF0 != (*((unsigned short*)(&x) + 3) & 0x7FF0))
```

Maybe `double.IsInfinity(x) == false` or `double.IsNegativeInfinity(x) == false`?

Thanks.

Comment: This is that '[new math](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_math)', right? :)

Comment: There may not be a like-for-like replacement. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: double class has IsInfinity method, if you are referring at doubles

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.jscript.globalobject.isfinite(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I need to translate C++ code to C#...

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk: "This method supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code. " (it's also part of the JScript assembly).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
!double.IsInfinity(x) && !double.IsNaN(x)
```

References:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/isfinite.html
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.isinfinity.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.isnan.aspx

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk Wow, apparently I totally misread the question, then.

Comment: Works almost as a replacement for the js implementation. [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mjNwWu)